# ValueError/tuple error that changes depending on how do I fix it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-colaboratory

This is the link to the project:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DxfumwXxJOgn-k8YK4_ikJlC5adxP11G?usp=sharing

There is an error on the third to last cell that ends up having an error depending on how I try to fix it. Currently it is on the third error being

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I don't know what is causing this error and if I keep all values from the spreadsheet it causes another type of value error or a tuple error.

Comment: `buySell = buySell(data)` what is the meaning of this line. This error comes when you have a size mismatch in columns of DataFrame

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: basically your columns `CUB`, `SMA30` and `SMA100` has different sizes than `buySekk[0]`. check the lengths of these.

Comment: how should I make SMA30 equal to SMA100? CUB is it's own thing that isn't used in the error cell.